# Configure asp.net mvc localhost/Products/News to localhost/Products,News

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to use comma instead of slash in routing path. Example

`localhost/products,news`

instead of

`localhost/products/news`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "CommaSeperated",
        "{controller},{action},{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
    );
```

**Update:**

I found the problem. Commas are not treated like slashes. You can skip parameters when you are using slashes but that's not the case with commas. When you use commas you have to give all that's in the route. So you should provide all 3 parameters or it will not work. http://domain.com/files,details,3 will work but http://domain.com/files,index won't. There isn't a second comma in that URL so it won't match the route. So you write another route before the first one.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "CommaSeperated1",
        "{controller},{action}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } 
    );
```

Comment: Have you inserted this one before the default route?

Comment: your code is my default and sinlge route. Try your code on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this url

[ASP.NET Mvc - nullable parameters and comma as separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905252/asp-net-mvc-nullable-parameters-and-comma-as-separator)