# Location.href is giving partial url

Tags: javascript

On a page URL like :

```
http:mysite.com/index.php?mact=News,cntnt01,detail,0&cntnt01articleid=3&cntnt01returnid=15
```

Using location.href will return

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?mact=News,cntnt01,detail,0
```

is there a way to get the full URL including `'...&cntnt01articleid=3&cntnt01returnid=15'`

Thanks

Henri

Comment: If you don't have a JavaScript, get one now, and try inspecting `window.location` (i.e. `console.dir(window.location)`)

Comment: Please post your code. Regardless of validity of your URL, `location.href` does return the whole thing for me.

Comment: @jsalonen `If you don't have a JavaScript` ???????? :O

Comment: Really. I don't know what I thought when I wrote that o_O

Comment: @Ray The URLS are hereabove and the code is:
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">function mailpage()
{
mail_str = "mailto:?subject= Check this link --> " + document.title;
mail_str += "&body= " + document.title;
mail_str += "... at: " + window.location.search;
location.href = mail_str;
}
</SCRIPT>

Comment: @user1464314, why are you assigning `mail_str` back to `location.href`? are you trying to force the default mail client to pop up and handle `<a href="mailto:blahblah">email me</a>`? if so, you just need to create an anchor link like I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If your URL was well-formatted then the querystring would be available in the `window.location.href`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

The comma is a reserved character in a URI and should not be used as a part of your querystring vales. Also, you should be URI-Encoding your url. This is done in javascript by calling [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

Related: [Can I use commas in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198606/can-i-use-commas-in-a-url)

Comment: Apparently (by me) window.location.href stops at the '&' sign. Unfortunately, this url is generated by a CMS and I cannot change it.

Comment: @user1464314 according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location), `window.location.href` should give the entire URI, including querystring.