# How can I use a comma in a URL?

Tags: url

When I add a comma in a URL it shows up as %2c% . But this [site](http://www.ucakbiletiuzmani.com/ara/gurcistan,lubnan,1)'s URL has a comma.

How do I write my URL so it appears to visitors as a comma and not as %2c%?

Comment: Some information regarding it is specified at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198606/can-i-use-commas-in-a-url.. Please check

Answer (score 2):

`%2c` is directly equivalent to a comma.  You shouldn't see any difference in behaviour between the two.  (Do you?)

Comment: I want . User see comma in url not %2c.

Answer (score 0):

The site you link to uses url rewriting, that's why commas are shown.
They are not generated through a post.

BR