# Javascript - sending command in a proper way while using get method

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I need to send to the embedded device following command as `GET` method but this value `continuouspantiltmove: String(pt)` is not properly sent to the `CGI` script via `Google Chrome`, as a result it fails.

I cant fix it in `CGI` script because its not managed by me as its an embedded device.

How can you submit it with `iFrame`? or correctly via `$.get` if `iframe` is not possible.

When i open the URL simply in `Google Chrome` URL then the `CGI` script works, but not working with `$.get` method.

[image]

```
function button_axisleft() {
  if(alr>100) {
    alr = 100;
  }

  if(alr<-100) {
    alr = -100;
  }  
  alr = alr - 1;  
  pt ="'" + alr + "," + aud + "'"; 

  $.get('http://192.168.1.59/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi', {
      camera: 1,
      continuouspantiltmove: String(pt),
      imagerotation: 0,
  }, function(msg) {
    console.log('OK');
  });
}
```

**EDIT:** working version

```
// PAN-TILT-ZOOM
// No need to modify in CGI
function button_axisleft() {
  if(alr>100) {
    alr = 100;
  }  
  if(alr<-100) {
    alr = -100;
  }  

  alr = alr - 1;  
  pt =alr + "," + aud;     
  $.get('http://192.168.1.59/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?continuouspantiltmove=' + pt, {
      camera: 1,
      imagerotation: 0,
  }, function(msg) {
    console.log('OK');
  });
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the title of your post? I don't see where you are trying to send a comma to anything.

Comment: I think he means command in the title.

Comment: ptz.cgi needs to receive `continuouspantiltmove=-100,-50&other=values`. When we use $.get to send -100,-50 it does not send the comma correctly as a result it fails

Comment: Oh, so you really mean comma, sorry.

Comment: YES - sir. you can see attached screen shot is showing the value is not correct where we were trying to send it as `-4,27`

Comment: The value in the screenshot "decodes" to `'-4,0'`. Do you need the `'` (quotes) around your numbers? Otherwise, the commas are URL-encoded to `%2C0`, which I think should be OK to handle server-side. Also, you don't need to use `String`. Just do `continuouspantiltmove: pt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned in the comments **you want this:**

```
continuouspantiltmove=-100,-50&other=values
```

**Then this will do it:**

```
function button_axisleft() {
    if (alr > 100) {
        alr = 100;
    }

    if (alr < -100) {
        alr = -100;
    }
    alr = alr - 1;
    pt = alr + "," + aud;

    $.get('http://192.168.1.59/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?continuouspantiltmove=' + pt, {
        camera: 1,
        imagerotation: 0,
    }, function (msg) {
        console.log('OK');
    });
}
```

You had extra single quotes (`'`) around the numbers in your pt variable. And, according to your comment, you don't want those, so I removed them. It also seems that jQuery automatically URL-encodes some characters, such as the comma, and that's why your query string was looking weird. By including the query parameter directly in your URL string, we can skip jQuery's auto-encoding.

*However, you should also check this out:*
[Can I use commas in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198606/can-i-use-commas-in-a-url)

Comment: Thanks, its working now. (just for the record. Some people told me i have to do it in CGI modification, which was completely wrong suggestion.)

Comment: Oh no, yeah, it was just an encoding thing. I'm glad this worked for you :)