# What does <int> mean in java?

Tags: java, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, what does it mean when a type is followed by angle brackets (as in List<Foo>)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218216/in-java-what-does-it-mean-when-a-type-is-followed-by-angle-brackets-as-in-list)

Exactly what it says on the tin - what does `<int>` mean in Java? I can't use Google here, since Google seems to ignore characters such as < and >, so I end up searching "What does int mean in Java". Can anyone help please? This doesn't just apply to `<int>`, it applies to anything inside <>.

Comment: Well, `<int>` is illegal in Java, so it's a pretty poor example to use.

Comment: It's part of java generics, though the example should be <Integer> as int is a primitive. A better example is List<Integer> which represents a list of integers.

Comment: Seems to be fine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463/split-out-ints-from-string)... anyway, what I mean is stuff in <>.

Comment: @Bluefire - that's C#.net, not Java.

Comment: :O k sorry D: They look so similar!

Comment: Still, perfectly reasonable for someone to answer what Generics are in the context of Java, and it's application to any class type (in this case Integer)

Comment: @azulflame: I don't care about rep, I care about helping the OP. I gave an answer (now deleted since I'm not happy about being insulted for it) that adressed the OP's issue, and am guilty only of taking a little while to embellish it with substance. Please don't be so quick to judge.

Comment: @DaveNewton: the "rep whore" term was bandied about. Truthfully, DaveRlz's comment above says much the same as my answer did, so the answer wasn't adding much to the conversation anyway (although it did come first).